# How to update parent view based on a selection made on Table View Controller Popup

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a ViewController with a button on it. Ref #1 in attached image.
Now clicking on the button open a Table View controller as a Popover. Ref #2 in attached image.
[image]

So far good.
Now i want to do is clicking on one of the rows in the table view i would like to close the Popover and update the #1 View controller based on what was clicked.

Using a Segue Show reloads the whole view controller from the bottom of the screen which i don't want. I just want the popup to close and view to be updated.

Trying to recreate a flow similar to the popups shows on itune.
[image]

How should i proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `NSNotificationCenter`
On `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` post the notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"desiredEventHappend" object:nil];
```

and in viewcontrollers `viewDidLoad`,add observer

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(someThingInterestingHappened:) name:@"desiredEventHappend" object:nil];
```

and Then implement the selector

```
- (void)someThingInterestingHappened:(NSNotification *)info
{
    NSLog(@"info : %@",info.userInfo);
    //update view controller
}
```

Comment: Thanks Saif for replying so quickly. This was a nice way to do it. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

In the table view controller class you are adding to the popover, add a property which contains a block to be exited when a selection is made. Something like:

```
@property (nonatomic,copy) void (^onSelect)(NSString *item);
```

Inside the table view controller, when an item is selected call:

```
self.onSelect(<insert item selected>);
```

I've used an NSString here but you could use anything.

You can do the same with the cells in the table if you wish, with the block being set in cellForRowAtIndexPath if you want the cells to tell the table and then the table to tell the code which created it.

In you main controller (1) when you create the table view controller simply do:

```
tableControllerYouCreated.onSelect=(NSString *itemSelected) {
  <insert main view update code>      
}];
```

This will allow a cell click to inform the table of the selection which can then inform the main view.

You can decide how to pop down the table popover as a separate issue.

Comment: Thanks Rory. I will try this option as well.

Comment: Notifications are usually used to allow background tasks, OS changes or other changes of global interest to be  passed to one or more interested parties. It is not generally used for 1:1 interface wiring where you know the relationship between controllers. As your app gets more complex, I think you will find direct coding like here more manageable. Note how all the apple APIs and Pickers are generally delegate and completion handler based. Its good to start coding using similar mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

Or in Swift 3...

On didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "desiredEventHappend"), object: nil)
```

On viewController/viewDidLoad:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.myFunction), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "desiredEventHappend"), object: nil)
```

and than the func.:

```
func myFunction(notification: NSNotification) {
//do anything
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How to update a Objective-c tableView with XIB's from a PopUp Swift ViewController.

in your pop up ViewController:
(inside the method from where you want to update the table). Your Swift Class.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("NotificationIdf", object: nil)
```

in the viewdidload method of parent view controller: (Obj-c class)

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(reloadTable:)
                                             name:@"NotificationIdf"
                                           object:nil];
```

finaly define the function in your parent view controller:(Obj-c class)

```
-(void)reloadTable:(NSNotification*)noti { [self.tableView beginUpdates];[self.tableView endUpdates]; [self.tableView reloadData]; }
```